# AppleScript new item added on subfolder

Tags: applescript

I've applied "add - new item alert" Folder Action Script on a folder. But its only gets triggered when a file is added to the root/main of that folder, not to its subfolders.

Is there any way to get Folder Actions be trigger when changes occur in subfolders? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's not possible unless you assign the folder action to every subfolder. However it's possible with AppleScriptObjC / Cocoa with GCD or FSEvents. But this is not trivial.

Comment: Thank you Vadian.